# Does running a cronjob in shared webhosting (in CPanel) support mod_rewrite'd URLs?

Tags: php, cron, shared-hosting, cpanel

I'm currently developing a PHP application where I have SEO friendly URLs, I'm planning on once finished production stage (off localhost) to purchase some shared webhosting and schedule a cronjob for one of the files.

Now I'm wondering does the shared webhosting CPanel cronjob scheduler support mod_rewrite'd URLs or will I need to pass the direct file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the php script via command line, then

You will need to pass the full file path.

But if the script can be run via web request then you can use `wget` to use the URL of the file which will be the SEO friendly one